# Why is [name] always main in MiniCssExtractPlugin for webpack?

Tags: webpack, mini-css-extract-plugin

In webpack when configuring the MiniCssExtractPlugin, I don't understand why [name] is always "main"?

```
 plugins: [
   new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'assets/css/[name].css' // where does the name "main" come from?
    }) 
  ]
```

How could I pass a variable in so that [name] is the name of my app and not "main" without hardcoding it in like `filename: 'assets/css/myapp.css'` ?

Webpack `output` config:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.js',
  output: {
    path: utils.resolve('/dist'),
  },
```

The wierd thing is that even Webpack creates the main bundle file as `main.js`. Why main?

Comment: What is the name that you've gave to your entry point?

Comment: @felixmosh no name, i dont have any such option set

Comment: Can you add your `output` part of your webpack config?

Comment: @felixmosh done :) also webpack creates the bundle javascript as `main.js`. Where is it getting the name `main` from?

Comment: As I've wrote, it comes from the name of the entry, you are using the **default** name which is `main` (https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/6f413ae2e63897aef5e1956cb1c351ab33f6dbfe/lib/EntryOptionPlugin.js#L76) :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `[name]` is the name of the entry point.

If the entry point is a `String` or `Array` webpack will use a a default entry name **main**, based on https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/6f413ae2e63897aef5e1956cb1c351ab33f6dbfe/lib/EntryOptionPlugin.js#L76.

You can provide your entry point as an object,

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: { myName: './src/app.js'},
  output: {
    path: utils.resolve('/dist'),
  },
  ...
}
```

which will change entry name to `myName`.

Comment: thank you that makes sense now. I didn't realise that `main` was the default name.